# Адаптивный дизайн. Как это делается?

Tags: html, css

Всем привет.
Я создаю сайты, все прекрасно. Сейчас в моду входит какой-то адаптивный дизайн, это то, чтобы на мобильных устройствах сайт открывался по-другому. Подскажите, как оптимизировать страницу сайта под мобильные устройства? Есть какие-нибудь полезные статейки, а то в Инете столько воды, ужас.

Comment: > Сейчас в моду входит какой то адаптивный дизайн

Лет пять назад

> как оптимизировать страницу сайта под мобильный устройства?

Есть такая штука как CSS Media Queries ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries), [habr](http://habrahabr.ru/post/119127/)). Они позволяют задавать условные правила CSS (в зависимости от ширины экрана), и, в общем, всё. Можно еще на бэкенде проверять User-Agent и модифицировать вывод, но что касательно дизайна - это просто несколько media queries для разных экранов.

Comment: И, кстати, можно просто отресайзить браузер, чтобы увидеть, как изменится верстка. У меня в хромиуме - кажется, нативно уже сделали, я вроде плагинов не ставил - есть вообще эмуляция конкретных устройств (user-agent + изменение размеров viewport).

Comment: Спасибо! Начнем изучать!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://htmlbook.ru/css/media

http://htmlbook.ru/css/value/media

Answer (score 1):

Начните с книжки "Ethan Marcotte - Responsive Web Design" издательства "A Book Apart". Книжка небольшая не нудная.